# How can i count the similar values in a Multidimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can i count the similar values in this 2d array? please help

```
var data = [[0,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[2,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[4,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[3,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[6,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0],[7,0]]
```

I want something like this

```
var data3d = [[0,0,1],[1,0,12],[2,0,25]......
```

I want to save in the 3rd space the count value

Comment: Could you please follow this guide on [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the reduce function as follows

```
const reducedArray= data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if(accumulator[currentValue]) accumulator[currentValue][2]++;
  else accumulator[currentValue] = [...currentValue, 1];
  return accumulator;
}, {});

const data3d = Object.values(reducedArray);
```